# Three.js: Error creating WebGL context (OSX El Capitan + Firefox 43.0.4)

Tags: macos, firefox, three.js, webgl, osx-elcapitan

Getting error while creating WebGL context in Three.js on OSX El Capitan and Firefox 43.0.4

Here is the app:
http://redsparkzone.com/logotest/

Is there any way to solve that problem?

[image]